# unknown syntax error in python

Tags: python, scripting

I did everything right from the [Monstercat Audio Visualization tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDaSk2mX7HU), but when I say run script, line 27 is said to be a syntax error. Here is the entire script. What am I doing wrong? I checked for commas instead of periods, even retyped it, checked mine against the video. Not sure what else to.

```
import bpy

for i in range(0,64):

    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(location = ((i + (i*0.5))), 0, 0)
    bpy.context.scene.cursor_location = bpy.context.active_object.location
    bpy.context.scene.cursor_location.y -= 1
    bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR')

    bpy.context.active_object.scale.x = 0.5
    bpy.context.active_object.scale.y = 20
    bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=False, scale=True)

    bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='Scaling')
    bpy.context.active_object.animation_data.action.fcurves[0].lock = True
    bpy.context.active_object.animation_dada.action.fcurves[2].lock = True

    bpy.context.area.type = 'GRAPH_EDITOR'

    l = i**2 + 20
    h = (i*1)**2 + 20

    print(str(i) + str(l) + str(h))

    bpy.ops.graph.sound_bake(filepath=r'C:\Users\H20\Videos\Youtube\Onyx Leaf\Nightcore\Take Me To Church\Take Me To Church.mp4' , low = (l), high = (h)

    bpy.context.active_object.animation_data.action.fcurves[1].lock = True
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Python syntax, not Blender.

Comment: Looks like it's on-topic http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/329/is-this-off-topic

Comment: Borderline but I think this is ok. As long as it isn't pure python, we can accept these.

Answer (score 7):

Line 25 is missing a closing bracket. Python assumes line 27 is part of the `high = (h)` parameter to the `sound_bake()` function.

```
    bpy.ops.graph.sound_bake(filepath=r'path/to/file' , low = (l), high = (h)
```

should be:

```
    bpy.ops.graph.sound_bake(filepath=r'path/to/file' , low = (l), high = (h))
```